# circle moving in a round path

Tags: javascript, html

How can i move a circle in a round path using HTML5 and javascript
My code to move circle in a linear path is given below. how can i change the path to a circular one?

```
 <script>

   var context;
   var x=100;
   var y=250;
   var dx=5;
   var dy=5;

    function move()
    {
     context= rectangle.getContext('2d');
     setInterval(draw,20);
    }

   function draw()
   {
    context.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle="#0000ff";

    context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();

    x+=dx;


   }
  </script>

    <canvas id="rectangle" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;" >
    </canvas>
    <input type="button" onClick="move();" width="100" height="100" value="click "/>

</body>
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear to be working in any browsers for me when I put it in a jsFiddle.

Comment: maybe looking at the code from this jquery plugin would give some clues as to how they are drawing their circles.  http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

Answer (score 1):

You have already done everything; now in order to move it in circle instead of on a line you need to choose a dƟ instead of dx, so that you can move both x and y coordinates.

Now lets say you have your center at (a,b) and radius of the path as r then your path will look as follows:

[image]

so there you have your coordinates r*cosƟ, r*sinƟ

so in your draw function do this

```
x=a+r*cos(Ɵ);
y=b+r*sin(Ɵ);
Ɵ+=dƟ;
```

instead of

```
x+=dx;
```

Choose dƟ in radian precisely so that the movement look smooth. 
[also choose some viable variable names instead of Ɵ and dƟ]